# Why is the Android App Icon not coming up in App Info and Clear Tasks?

Tags: android, icons, android-drawable

I have successfully changed the App Icon for the Android App and is being displayed properly in Menu with logo and app name as iTest Game.

[App Icon in Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdPrK.png)

But the app icon is not coming in App Info and in Clear Tasks.

[App Icon in App Info & Clear Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH8ch.png)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.itestgame">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity1" />
        <activity android:name=".GameOver" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity3" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity4" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity5" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity6" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My phone models are Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 and Samsung Galaxy Grand Quattro.
I am not able to figure out why the App Icon is not coming at these places.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your manifest file

Comment: @ArpitPatel Sure, just a moment please.

Comment: tried clean build?

Comment: @Kakumanusivakrishna The app icon 'ic_launcher.png' is in res -> mipmap.

Comment: @jagapathi Yes, I have tried the clean build, uninstalled and reinstalled the clean build app again on device.

Comment: android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round". Check for this icon whether you placed actual one or default one

Comment: @Kakumanusivakrishna Yes, this is the cause. I think this should fix the issue :) . Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome bro

Comment: Some one will know the answer. Up vote it bro.

Comment: @Kakumanusivakrishna Sure, I have upvoted it. But it won't be visible as I don't have 15+ reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for the issue is:

1. Change the default icon to the new app logo at both **android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"** and **android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"**
2. Try Clean Build, uninstall and re-install the app.

Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: If someone reading this is using cordova, you can use the <edit-config> tag in the config.xml to add this to the manifest. Doing it manually will lead to it being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the round icon you placed in mipmap folder.

```
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```